# Hierarchical queries

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I've created some sort of "dependencies" table that contain the entire dependencies of ours night process.

The table looks like this:

```
GRAND_MODEL | WAIT_4_MODEL_NAME
test            test1
test            test2
test            test3
test2           test3
test3           test4
test4           test5
```

This table means -> `test` needs to wait for `test1` , `test2`, `test3` in order to finish, but also it needs to wait for `test4` and `test5` , because `test3/4` waits for them .
`test1` doesn't wait for anything , `test2` waits for `test3` and therefore also for `test4` and therefore `test5` .

So the result should look something like this:

```
FIRST_MODEL | SECOND_MODEL | THIRD_MODEL | FORTH_MODEL | FIFTH_MODEL | SIXTH_MODEL
 test5           test4            test3       test2          test        NULL 
 test5           test4            test3       test           NULL        NULL
 test4           test3            test2       test           NULL        NULL
.................................
```

What I've tried :

```
SELECT distinct prior wait_4_model_name as first_m,
                wait_4_model_name as second_m,
                grand_model as third_m
  from (SELECT distinct grand_model, wait_4_model_name
          FROM DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY)
connect by NOCYCLE prior grand_model = wait_4_model_name
```

But that only generates the first level of the hierarchy.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Note that there can be opposite dependencies , `test` waits for `test1` and `test1` waits for `test` (each model is big, so it's possible for a part of the model to wait for a part of another model)

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of levels in the hierarchy?

Comment: No, but lets say 9 is enough. @MT0

Comment: Regarding your edit: So, if there are reciprocal dependencies, you will have infinite sequences, no? What is the desired output then? Do you break cycles the "CONNECT BY NOCYCLE" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( GRAND_MODEL, WAIT_4_MODEL_NAME ) AS
SELECT 'test',  'test1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test',  'test2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test',  'test3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2', 'test3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test3', 'test4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test4', 'test5' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 1 ) AS first_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 2 ) AS second_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 3 ) AS third_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 4 ) AS fourth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 5 ) AS fifth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 6 ) AS sixth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 7 ) AS seventh_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 8 ) AS eighth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 9 ) AS ninth_model
FROM   (
  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( wait_4_model_name, '|' ) || '|' ||  grand_model AS tests
  FROM  table_name
  CONNECT BY PRIOR grand_model = wait_4_model_name
);
```

**Output**:

```
FIRST_MODEL SECOND_MODEL THIRD_MODEL FOURTH_MODEL FIFTH_MODEL SIXTH_MODEL SEVENTH_MODEL EIGHTH_MODEL NINTH_MODEL
----------- ------------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------ -----------
test1       test                                                                                                 
test2       test                                                                                                 
test3       test                                                                                                 
test3       test2                                                                                                
test3       test2        test                                                                                    
test4       test3                                                                                                
test4       test3        test                                                                                    
test4       test3        test2                                                                                   
test4       test3        test2       test                                                                        
test5       test4                                                                                                
test5       test4        test3                                                                                   
test5       test4        test3       test                                                                        
test5       test4        test3       test2                                                                       
test5       test4        test3       test2        test
```

Comment: After a few adjustments , it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: To bad this solution concatenates strings, to then split them again, also requiring that the delimiter does not occur in the data itself.

Comment: Kindly look on my following question to this one here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551931/selecting-best-output :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require string concatenation and re-split:

```
select    a.wait_4_model_name model1,
          a.grand_model       model2,
          b.grand_model       model3,
          c.grand_model       model4,
          d.grand_model       model5,
          e.grand_model       model6
from      DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY a
left join DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY b ON a.grand_model = b.wait_4_model_name
left join DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY c ON b.grand_model = c.wait_4_model_name
left join DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY d ON c.grand_model = d.wait_4_model_name
left join DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY e ON d.grand_model = e.wait_4_model_name
where     a.wait_4_model_name not in (
              select grand_model from DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY)
order by  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Output for the sample data is:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| MODEL1 | MODEL2 | MODEL3 | MODEL4 | MODEL5 | MODEL6 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| test1  | test   |    -   |   -    |   -    |   -    |
| test5  | test4  | test3  | test   |   -    |   -    |
| test5  | test4  | test3  | test2  | test   |   -    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Note that your sample data has no instances of models that do not have any dependencies at all, i.e. that do not need to wait for another model, nor are necessary for any models before they can start.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I prefer hierarchical queries on this, but +1 for the idea. I'll appreciate you having a look on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551931/selecting-best-output

Comment: The performance of this will not be great as you need one table scan for each level of the hierarchy.

Comment: Only if you don't put indexes on those fields. With proper indexes set it is not a table scan. In fact, with the index properly set the engine does not even have to access the table itself, it can do it all with the index.