# Selecting best output

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

This question relate to my latest question [here .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550821/hierarchical-queries/38551174#38551174)

**Note:** This question is in Oracle, but the solution may also be in MySQL , so you can choose the one you prefer.

I've come up with a query the generate the hierarchy dependecies between my models, which result in an output like this:

```
FIRST_MODEL SECOND_MODEL THIRD_MODEL FOURTH_MODEL FIFTH_MODEL SIXTH_MODEL SEVENTH_MODEL EIGHTH_MODEL NINTH_MODEL
----------- ------------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------ -----------
test1       test                                                                                                 
test2       test
test2       test6                                                                                                 
test3       test                                                                                                 
test3       test2                                                                                                
test3       test2        test     
test3       test2        test6                                                                                    
test4       test3                                                                                                
test4       test3        test                                                                                    
test4       test3        test2                                                                                   
test4       test3        test2       test   
test4       test3        test2       test6 
.....
```

ETC.., which means `FIRST_MODEL` waits for `SECOND_MODEL` and so on..

The problem is that I have to select the **most completed** output from here, which basically means only the "leaves" and only the "leaves" that are filled in with the most data, an example on the data will be provided in a bit. Here is a dummy example :

```
First | Second | Third | Forth | Fifth ....
 1       2        null    null    null
 1       2        6       null    null
 1       2        5       null    null
 1       2        5       7       null
 1       3        null    null    null
 1       4        6       null
```

The result should be

```
First | Second | Third | Forth | Fifth ....
 1       2        6       null    null
 1       2        5       7       null
 1       4        6       null    null
```

Every thing else got excluded because they are a part of the selected output.

so a query with `ROW_NUMBER()` or something will not work,

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ????? ORDER BY ???
FROM <Another Query>
```

I don't know how to partition by an unknown set of columns.

E.G. The output here should be :

```
test4       test3        test2       test   
test4       test3        test2       test6
```

Because everything else, is just a part of those two result . I'm really stuck on this , I don't see which window function can I use becuase each group changes each time, the levels of hierarchy are unknown and can change.

I prefer to avoid dynamic SQL, I know it can be done using a Procedure and I also know how to built one, but I got a requirement to avoid it.

I'll also provide the query that creates the data which is built in Oracle with Hierarchical queries , maybe someone will have an idea about taking only the most completed row from the start:

```
SELECT distinct REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 1 ) AS first_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 2 ) AS second_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 3 ) AS third_model,
       ......
FROM   (
  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( wait_4_model_name, '|' ) || '|' ||  grand_model AS tests
  FROM  (SELECT * FROM Tab_Name)
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR grand_model = wait_4_model_name
)
```

For more info about the data you can enter my last question in the link above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) I removed the mysql tag (the code is clearly Oracle and MySQL doesn't support hierarchical/recursive queries).  (2) What do you mean by "most completed output"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Note the `P.S.` part, the solution can also be in MySQL. , (2) - I mean the one with the most levels of hierarchy, the "leaves"

Comment: . . You can leave the MySQL tag, but your existing code is all in Oracle and cannot be replicated in MySQL with a single `SELECT`.  The tag is useless and potentially confusing.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the data sample I provided can be exist in a table in MySQL, so the Oracle query won't even matter.. I've only added the query because I though maybe people will have an idea how to do it at the beginning, couldn't found a nicer way to explain it :D @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( GRAND_MODEL, WAIT_4_MODEL_NAME ) AS
SELECT 'test',  'test1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test',  'test2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test',  'test3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2', 'test3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test3', 'test4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test4', 'test5' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 1 ) AS first_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 2 ) AS second_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 3 ) AS third_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 4 ) AS fourth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 5 ) AS fifth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 6 ) AS sixth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 7 ) AS seventh_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 8 ) AS eighth_model,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( tests, '[^|]+', 1, 9 ) AS ninth_model
FROM   (
  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( wait_4_model_name, '|' ) || '|' ||  grand_model AS tests
  FROM  table_name
  WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH wait_4_model_name NOT IN ( SELECT grand_model FROM table_name )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR grand_model = wait_4_model_name
);
```

**Output**:

```
FIRST_MODEL SECOND_MODEL THIRD_MODEL FOURTH_MODEL FIFTH_MODEL SIXTH_MODEL SEVENTH_MODEL EIGHTH_MODEL NINTH_MODEL
----------- ------------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------ -----------
test1       test                                                                                                 
test5       test4        test3       test                                                                        
test5       test4        test3       test2        test
```

Comment: Hah, I knew there's got to be some hierarchy function that will solve this easily . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most levels, you can do get them in order:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select t.*
from t
order by ((case when first_model is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when second_model is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
          . . .
         ) desc;
```

You can choose the top one using `fetch first 1 row only` (Oracle 12c+) or using a subquery.

Alternatively, you can keep the full `tests` string, and count the number of `|` in it:

```
order by regexp_count(tests, '[|]') desc
```

You can do something similar using `row_number()`:

```
with . . .
select
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by <group> order by regexp_count(tests, '[|]') desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

It is not clear from the question how you are defining a group.

Comment: But won't that treat the two output rows in my example the same? Both have the same number of `NULL` columns, but they are different.. For instanace, `1,2,4,null..` and `1,2,5,6,null` and `1,2,5,7,null...` are all different rows that I don't want to exclude them from the result set. The rows I'd like to exclude will be `1,2,null...` and `1,2,5,null..` because a longer version of them exists

Comment: @sagi . . . This follows the definition of "most completed output" in your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess I forgot to say "For each group" , which is dynamic ... Added the information to the question.

Comment: @sagi . . . So move the `order by` clause into a `row_number()` function and use it there.

Comment: That's not what I meant.. I can't define a group because it's dynamic, a group can be 1 column, 3 column or all the columns.. I've managed to overcome this problem, you can look at my answer for better understanding what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution using `LAG()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` , by ordering the result of the inner query by all columns, i get the **more filled** records before the records that only **part of them** is filled, then, with `LAG()` I check if the concatenation of all columns is inside the concatenation of the last record, if so - filter it.

E.G.

```
FIRST | SECOND | THIRD | FORTH ... | RNK | IND_TO_EXCLUDE
  1        2       3       null       1        0
  1        2       4       null       2        0
  1        2       null    null       3        1
  2        3       5       null       4        0 
  ............
```

Rnk = 3 will get ind 1, because the concatenation of all the columns (12) is inside the concatenation of the last record columns (123) .

```
SELECT first_model,second_model,third_model,fourth_model,fifth_model,sixth_model,seventh_model,eighth_model,ninth_model
FROM (       
SELECT first_model,second_model,third_model,fourth_model,fifth_model,sixth_model,seventh_model,eighth_model,ninth_model,
       CASE
         WHEN INSTR(LAG(t.all_level, 1) OVER(ORDER BY t.rnk), t.all_level) > 0 THEN
          1
         ELSE
          0
       END as ind_to_exclude
  FROM (SELECT s.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY first_model, second_model, third_model, fourth_model, fifth_model, sixth_model, seventh_model, eighth_model, ninth_model) as rnk,
               NVL(s.first_model, '') || NVL(s.second_model, '') ||
               NVL(s.third_model, '') || NVL(s.fourth_model, '') ||
               NVL(s.fifth_model, '') || NVL(s.sixth_model, '') ||
               NVL(s.seventh_model, '') || NVL(s.eighth_model, '') ||
               NVL(s.ninth_model, '') as all_level
          FROM (SELECT distinct REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 1) AS first_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 2) AS second_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 3) AS third_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 4) AS fourth_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 5) AS fifth_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 6) AS sixth_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 7) AS seventh_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 8) AS eighth_model,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(tests, '[^|]+', 1, 9) AS ninth_model
              FROM (SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(wait_4_model_name, '|') || '|' ||
                           grand_model AS tests
                      FROM (SELECT *
                              FROM DEL_SAGI_FOR_HIERARCHY
                             WHERE grand_model NOT IN ('Dwh_0_Start_Flow','Dwh_99_End_Flow','create_flag_4_runing')
                               AND wait_4_model_name NOT IN ('Dwh_0_Start_Flow','Dwh_99_End_Flow','create_flag_4_runing')
                               AND co_dependent = 0)
                        CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                         PRIOR grand_model = wait_4_model_name)) s
                         ) t
                )  tt
WHERE tt.ind_to_exclude = 0
```